# Unable to reference System.Windows.Media.AudioFormat in universal app

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I’ve got a bit of a poser here: I am developing a Universal app targeting Windows 8.1. In this app I need to use System.Windows.Media.AudioFormat.

My projects already include references to Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 respectively, since I started with a universal app. The object browser tells me that both assemblies include `System.Windows.Media.AudioFormat` – but whenever I try to reference the class, I get

> “The type or namespace name 'Media' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)”

If I scope the object browser to look only at Windows Phone 8.1, it shows `Media.AudioFormat` as part of `System.Windows`. If I scope the object browser to my solution, `System.Windows` shows as empty. It almost looks as if my reference to Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't add the whole of itself to my solution.

If I use the handy little button in the object browser that lets you add a reference for whatever namespace is currently selected in the object browser, I get a message telling me that System.Windows was successfully added, but I still get the error that I’m missing an assembly reference.

I gather that this class is part of the `System.Windows.dll.` If I try to add this by browsing to it, I get an error message telling me that this dll can’t be added because it’s already automatically referenced by the build system.

Visual Studio (Community 2013) doesn’t allow me to delete the references to Windows 8.1, so I can’t try to remove them and then add them again. Neither can I change the target .NET framework to see if that’s where the error might come from.

I’m stumped. Can anybody help, please?

Comment: This might sound like a stupid question, but: Are you also referencing it with the using-command?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with both a using statement and referencing the full path in my variable declaration. Neither can even see the media namespace, let alone the AudioFormat class.

Comment: That's a Silverlight class, not universal.  Very unclear what you are trying to do, but at least get an [audio sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/audiocreation) working to get the lay of the land.

Comment: I already have my audio processing working in a project I did a while ago, but the original project was a windows phone 8.0 one. Now I need to re-use some of the code I have in an 8.1 universal app, but the references don't seem to include the classes I need. If you could point me to where I can find the correct Silverlight dlls, I'd be very grateful.